# For all $e\ge 0,z>0,e,z\in\Bbb Q$, there exists $m\in \Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $e<\dfrac{m}{2^n}<e+z$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> For all $e\ge 0,z>0,e,z\in\Bbb Q$, there exists $m\in \Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $e<\dfrac{m}{2^n}<e+z$.

---

Does my proof look fine or contain logical gaps and flaws? I'm pleased to receive your suggestion!

---

**My attempt:**

It suffices to prove that for all $e\ge 0$ and for all $1>z>0$, there exist $m\in \Bbb Z,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $$e<\dfrac{m}{2^n}<e+z$$

We have three cases in total.

1. $e \in \Bbb Z$

Let $n'=\min\{n\in\Bbb N\mid\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}<z\}$. Then $e+\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}$ has a form of $\dfrac{m}{2^n}$ and $e<e+\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}<e+z$.

2. $e<a<e+z$ for some $a\in Z$

Let $n'=\min\{n\in\Bbb N\mid\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}<z\}$. Then $a+\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}$ has a form of $\dfrac{m}{2^n}$ and $e<a+\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}<e+z$.

3. $a<e<e+z\le a+1$ for some $a\in Z$

Let $n'=\min\left\{\min\{n\in\Bbb N\mid \dfrac{1}{2^n}\le e-a\} ,\min\{ n\in\Bbb N\mid\dfrac{1}{2^n}<z\}\right\}$. Notice that $n'\ge 1$.

It follows that $\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}\le e-a$ and $\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}<z$ and $\dfrac{1}{2^{n'-1}}> e-a$ and $\dfrac{1}{2^{n'-1}}\ge z$.

Thus $e-a < \dfrac{1}{2^{n'-1}} = \dfrac{2}{2^{n'}}=\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{n'}}<(e-a)+z$.

Hence $e<\dfrac{2}{2^{n'}}+a<e+z$ where $\dfrac{2}{2^{n'}}+a$ has a form of $\dfrac{m}{2^n}$.

Comment: I have no idea why this is tagged as set theory.

Comment: Why is e an integer?

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila! I have changed the tag. Please edit if you find a more appropriate one!

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot! I divide into three cases and $e\in\Bbb Z$ is just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $n$ with $1 < z×2^n$.

Find $m$ with $e×2^n < m \le e×2^n + 1$.

Comment: I got your solution. It's much simpler and elegant than mine. Could you confirm if my proof is correct?

Comment: No.  It's too complicated.  BTW, e = .9, z = .1 falls into none of those cases.

Comment: Oh I see. I have adjusted the case 3. from $a<e<e+z< a+1$ to $a<e<e+z\le a+1$. This adjustment does not change anything in the proof. My approach is unnecessarily complicated. I will not use it anymore. I just want to check if my reasoning is correct. :)